# Can I override the color of a title bar on a specific application in windows?

Tags: windows, labview

I have a coworker who needs to have multiple versions of LabVIEW on his computer. He has a bad habit of opening LV2010 code in LV2013. LabVIEW doesn't warn that you are about to change all of the code to a new version of LabVIEW, and this breaks the code running on a test system on the production floor.

Here is my question: does anyone know of any kind of hack or legitimate method of changing the windows title bar for a single application? I would like to be able to change the color of the title bar only on LabVIEW 2013 from blue to red or something.

If this isn't possible, does anyone have an idea of how to distinguish one application from another that looks almost identical?

Thanks for any advice you have to give.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the good news is that LabVIEW 2014 on will have the version number in their icon. That doesn't help your situation much, though. I'm not sure about changing the title bar, but I think I can help with your second question.

The icons for those versions are indistinguishable, however, the mass compile LabVIEW does when you open a project from an older version is a dead giveaway. You know LabVIEW is performing a mass compile if, while the project is loading, "Compiling:" appears where "Loading:" normally does. Close out of LabVIEW without saving and open the right version of LabVIEW. If he still goofs, there's always reverting in whatever version control software you're (hopefully) using, and you can always save back to older versions in LabVIEW itself.

I currently have four (older) versions installed to support projects that are under warranty. One trick I've found to be helpful is to put a .txt document in the same directory I save my .lvproj with the LabVIEW version as the title. For example, if the code is written in LabVIEW 2012 I include a text document called LV2012.txt in my _Project folder. Not a foolproof plan, but it has definitely made me double check my open version of LabVIEW before double-clicking.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use get VI version property described here: http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/0C72D335AA87DD6486256FC40069C17F

Than using version information change you title bar text or transparency(I am not sure about color) or other FP component using VI ref property node.